# How i can skip filter for static content?

Tags: java, servlets, web, filter

In my web-app i have front filter that is acting like router. It just routes to proper controller and action according to request url. To do that i added following in my WEB.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>FrontFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>service.FrontFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>FrontFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

But the problem is that if i want just get static html page. My filter is invoked too and starts to find controller and action. And of course it fails. I tried to place all my static content to /public folder and do in filter something like that:

```
if (reqURI.contains("/public/")) {
           chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

but with no success. 
So, how i can skip filter for static content like images and just html? I will highly appreciate your any response.

Answer (score 3):

In your case to skip the filter for html file urls, Try

```
if (reqURI.endsWith(".html")) {
    chain.doFilter(request, response); 
}
```

Comment: can you please show what you are getting in reqURI??

Comment: i just commented my filter and pasted this to get reqURI:

Comment: response.getOutputStream().print(((HttpServletRequest) request).getRequestURI()); my request URI is /shop/static.html